# Broadcast "JOIN" in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-flink, flink-sql

Is there any way I can use Broadcast Join in FLINK the same way I used in SPARK. I'm working with JOINS but the data is large so I would require Broadcast Join.

Thank You

Comment: Not very sure what exactly you want. Is this what you want?  https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html

Comment: Hi @JiayiLiao do you know what broadcast join do in spark? Here's a link for you to follow :- https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html

It'd be really great if you could help me with this.
I want same functioning in flink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink does not provide a broadcast join like the one in Spark. It's pretty easy to implement one yourself using a `BroadcastProcessFunction`, but I wonder if it is really appropriate. A broadcast join only makes sense if one of the two streams is fairly small, otherwise a key-partitioned join makes a lot more sense.

To implement this, broadcast the smaller pattern stream and connect it to the event stream. In the processBroadcastElement method of a BroadcastProcessFunction, store the new pattern, and in the processElement method lookup the relevant pattern and combine it with the event that is being processed.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, Thanks for your answer, I need it while joining two DataStreams, Yes there's quite a large difference in the size of the two

Comment: can you tell me with  a snippet how to use it? if one table is named event and the other one as patt 
Link :- https://github.com/ASKRAJPUT5/flink-Table/blob/master/src/main/scala/flinkTable25.scala